# Getting Connection Refused error even though the tasks are running inside ecs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy flask python application in aws using ecs. My Ecs tasks are running and inside ecs logs, I can see that the server has been started. But still when I issue the public ip in browser, it shows connection refused error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihHSC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIKn2.png)

I have added security groups rule but still can't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added the correct security group rule (you didn't provide any actual details about that in your question) your problem is most likely because you have bound Flask to `127.0.0.1`. So it will currently only accept network requests from inside localhost (the container). You need to change Flask to bind to `0.0.0.0` so that it will accept requests from anywhere.